Cannot liveboot any ubuntu-based system
I can't boot any ubuntu-based linux from USB, arch-based work flawlessly.
Currently I'm trying to liveboot (and then install) Ubuntu 24.04 amd64.
Grub displays fine, OS logo shows, but then after a while list of errors shows, i.e.:
usb usb2-port3: unable to enumerate USB device
usb 1-3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
usb 2-3: device not accepting address 108, error -32
Tried different live usb creation methods (cp, cat, Rufus, ISOImageWriter) and many linux distributions, every time the same errors are shown.

I suggest you provide specifics of what you are trying to boot, and please note Ubuntu based systems such as Linux Mint, Pop OS etc are off-topic here as they actually differ to Ubuntu, however Ubuntu flavors and products are on-topic. There are slight variations in how ISOs boot between releases so being specific is helpful (Ubuntu is created for many architectures; and all architectures will boot the same for a given release, thus slight differences between releases do exist). If re-formatting ISO you must use correct software & options for your release & hardware; so check method!

FYI:  If you write ISO using documented method; Ubuntu ISOs are QA tested to boot & install on legacy devices, uEFI & Secure-uEFI devices.. however if you reformat ISO during write that won't apply; with results specific to how the ISO was written.. A direct clone of ISO to media is usually best; but you've not mentioned what architecture, what ISO of what Ubuntu product/release, if you checked ISO checksum, or write of ISO to media etc..  Booting ISOs using revoked keys, incorrect architecture & other user mistakes could also apply; I suggest checking your procedures

FYI:  64-bit isn't very specific; as there is AMD64, ARM64, PPC64EL, RISCV64.... or multiple 64-bit options;   though as ARM is the only 32-bit OR 64-bit you maybe trying to specify ARM64 but it's best if you're specific.
